# Issue with the jcarousel

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have an issue with the jcarousel items. The half on an image from the jcarousel dissapear when I resize the browser. You can check the template here. If you resize until you see only two images ( items ) in jcarousel, you will see my issue. I've tried everything, I can't simply solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the existing margins you would need to reduce the size of the  .jcarousel-item
for each image to show each image fully within the given space when the browser gets below 767px in width.

You could add the following code under a media query

```
.jcarousel-item {
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 199px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just inspecting your site. It looks like your problem stems from the CSS on line 135 of your style.css file. Notably the margin attribute.

```
.container {
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

I think that you can solve this problem by doing something like:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.